# ASP.NET Web Api 2 - Change default validation messages for models site wide

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Say I have a model, like this:

```
class Model
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to make it so that rather than the error message being:

> The Name field is required.

I can change it to:

> Name is required.

I would like to do this without making my own attributes and without adding an `ErrorMessage = x` to all of my attributes.

When searching I found some stuff that seemed to apply to MVC2, but nothing web api specific. I got as far as creating an attribute adapter:

```
public class CustomRequiredAttributeAdapter : DataAnnotationsModelValidator< RequiredAttribute>
{
    public CustomRequiredAttributeAdapter(ModelMetadata metadata, ModelBindingExecutionContext context, RequiredAttribute attribute)
    : base(metadata, context, attribute)
    {
        attribute.ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.";
    }
}
```

But registering it like this:

```
var validatorProvider = new DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider();
validatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(RequiredAttribute), typeof(CustomRequiredAttributeAdapter));       
webApiConfig.Services.Replace(typeof(System.Web.Http.Validation.ModelValidatorProvider), validatorProvider);
```

in my startup didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out that I was implementing the wrong type of `DataAnnotationsModelValidator`

I should have been using the one from the `System.Web.Http.Validation.Validators` namespace. Like this:

```
public class CustomRequiredAttributeAdapter : DataAnnotationsModelValidator
{
    public CustomRequiredAttributeAdapter(IEnumerable<ModelValidatorProvider> validatorProviders, ValidationAttribute attribute)
    : base(validatorProviders, attribute)
    {
        attribute.ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.";
    }
}
```

Then register it as I did above :)